# Trouble changing a globale variable from an event handler

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I´m builing a simple app in ionic4 that has a button. When the button is pressed then the accelerometer alpha value should be displayed. My problem is that the eventhandler that the event listner invokes does not change the globale variable (I think)

```
public sensordata: any;

handleOrientation(event) {
this.sensordata = event.alpha;
}

clicked() {
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation, true);
}
```

```html
<ion-button id="btn" (click)="clicked()" expand="block">Show sensor data</ion-button>
<ion-text>The sensor data is {{sensordata}}</ion-text>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to describe your debugging steps that lead you the the conclusion that the global variable was not changed.

Comment: why would you add an event listener when you can just attach `handleOrientation` to your `(click)` event?, essentially `(click)="handleOrientation($event)"`

Comment: Also `this` in the event listener is a reference to the html button the event is attached to not the component class, there is no need for you to attach an event listener when the element has access to any function specified within the component class.

Comment: @Bargros It want continuous update of the value

Comment: Whenever you click the button `handleOrientation` will be triggered and the value updated, so I don't understand what you mean by continuous update of the value?. Also you do realise `clicked` only creates the event listener again and again, its function is not to update the value but simply re-attach the event listener continuously.

Comment: Okay, so I want the button to turn on an event listner so the values continuously change (attaching it to the button press will just pull the data in that exact time)

Comment: Where does the sensor data come from?

Comment: AS suggested already you might want to change `clicked() {}` to `clicked = () => {}` as lambda expressions don't implement their own `this` object. This has already been mentioned below, check it out.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that "this" is probably not what you think it is. Have you tried changing the function

```
clicked() {
 window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation, true);
}
```

to

```
clicked = () => {
 window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.handleOrientation, true);
}
```

Comment: `clicked()` and `clicked = () =>`  are the same thing but declared in two different ways.

Comment: No. The difference is the “this”-pointer, which varies i the two cases.

Comment: I don't see any differences between the two but what I already stated

Comment: Then you will have something to learn about javascript. Look this example, play around with it, and see that the way the function is declared can be very important: https://plnkr.co/edit/UOjJYDIJmg1Ni9aOt036?p=preview

Comment: And also I don't get why you are confused about this. You wrote the exact same thing as a comment to the original question... Where you also commented that the "this" pointer could be a problem.

Comment: I see your point, `click = () =>` doesn't implement its own `this` object and will refer to the actual class instead. I did learn something new about JavaScript, thank you.